How do I exclude a certain column from feature extraction in tsfresh?
I'm using tsfresh to extract features comprehensively from a timeseries. I wish to exclude certain columns in my dataset from feature extraction (i.e., absolute energy, min, max, etc. shouldn't be computed based on a list of certain columns I can specify in a function or somewhere else).
Is there any way I can do this in tsfresh without having to remove the specific column(s) from the pandas DataFrame to be input to tsfresh.feature_extraction.extraction.extract_features() or drop features starting with the specific column name(s) after the feature extraction is complete?
